# FluentAssertions: how to set breakpoint inside lambda

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

FluentAssertions is a great library but often I am very frustrated when some code in lambda is not working as expected and I cannot debug it. Especially when lambda is complicated.

```
payload.Resource.Relations.Removed.Should().NotBeNull()
            .And.HaveCount(2)
            .And.AllBeOfType<ResourceRelation>()
            .And.OnlyContain(rel => 
    rel.RelationType.MatchTo(RelationType.ArtifactLink) && 
    rel.Href.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(VsTfsSchema.GitPullRequestId));
```

In this case, I would like to set a breakpoint into inside `OnlyContain(...)` lambda and debug it. But this is not possible - breakpoint is set always at the whole statement. I suppose that the reason is that lambdas in FluentAssertions are expressions.

Is there any way how to achieve this?

**Edit**: Extracting lambda as local variable does not help. Behavior is the same.

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<ResourceRelation, bool>> predicate = rel =>
            rel.RelationType.MatchTo(RelationType.ArtifactLink) && rel.Href.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(VsTfsSchema.GitPullRequestId);

payload.Resource.Relations.Removed.Should().NotBeNull()
    .And.HaveCount(2)
    .And.AllBeOfType<ResourceRelation>()
    .And.OnlyContain(predicate);
```

**Edit2**: Here is really simple and verifiable example. You cannot put a breakpoint into `num == 1`, nor extract it as local function, nor display it at watch.

```
[Fact]
public void SimpleLambdaTest()
{
    int[] nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray();
    nums.Should().OnlyContain(num => num == 1);
}
```

Comment: `Debugger.Break`?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: No, you cannot use Debugger.Break in an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the expression body into a static function, in which you can set a breakpoint.

Note that `EqualsOne` cannot be a local function and cannot be passed as a method group.

```cs
[Fact]
public void SimpleLambdaTest()
{
    int[] nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray();
    nums.Should().OnlyContain(num => EqualsOne(num));
}

private static bool EqualsOne(int num)
{
    // You can put a break point here
    return num == 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trapped into "Expressions mystery" and missed so simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

Although this has nothing to do with FluentAssertions, I do this quite often with Jetbrains Rider. When you try to set a breakpoint, it'll ask you *where* you want to have it; on the entire line, on an individual lambda, etc. I haven't debugged with Visual Studio for almost two years now, so I don't know if it can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Even if so, if you hit F11 on the breaked line debug should take you to the lambda expression. If not, you can still use `Add Watch` or `Quick Watch` facility (Select the lambda expression -> right click and select Quick Watch)

Comment: No, this does not work also. I can display predicate in a debugger, but it is expression also. Also, what value could be displayed, if the breakpoint is not inside the lambda? This is what I see in Watch:
`+  predicate {rel => (rel.RelationType.MatchTo("ArtifactLink") AndAlso rel.Href.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId"))} System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Scia.Cid.AppServer.Tfs.Api.Payloads.ResourceRelation, bool>> {System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1<System.Func<Scia.Cid.AppServer.Tfs.Api.Payloads.ResourceRelation, bool>>}`